# Signature value of secure aadhar qr code decoding gives bytes. What is the correct format it should be converted to?

Tags: java, byte, decode, qr-code, signature

I am following  [this document](https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/User_manulal_QR_Code_15032019.pdf)  to decode a secure QR code.

As mentioned in the document, I am able to decode the other values by reading the first 255 values of the `decompressByteArray`, but I am sure about what format should I convert the signature bytes to.

I am getting the following response for signature,which is in bytes.

```
¶Æv0Z@B`?ÍÄfí¼tZ(ÜëÖì@Üö`WØÜË_F*ª>Z®0åxÉ÷Þ©lk Kã7ï°Ãõ§+ÔYX/ã´ô¤< 7Zék6AxÌ1<7[ä·d¹2NÃõæGæ´îcEÈÙ÷a7ìx#óËJóG¸FÏ*£cñøó2ø³@ã/?¸jI®ú°¨«hÞæcë¥ÒcßÝ4^AÞ§*©~ò¦Í+ÈAVÃ{fÃô¦jÊÖ¦È|úØ
$¿aqÛüÄKT¿þià=³.x
```

I am using the following code snippet to achieve it:

```
for(int i=0,j=decompressedBytes.length-1; i<256 & j>decompressedBytes.length-256-1 ; i++,j--)
    {
        signbytes[i] = decompressedBytes[j];
    }
sign = new String(signbytes,0,255,"ISO-8859-1");
```

How should I convert it into some suitable format?

Comment: Hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64341259/8362967